# How can i use a css selector in a meta tag text

Tags: html, css

I have this meta tag, `<meta name="keywords" content="brands">` and i want to use a custom css for every page that contains the content="brands" .
Is it possible for me to select the "brands" ? 
for example i tried this

```
meta[content*=brands] a#FWcategorynamelink {display: none !important;}
```

is it possible to do sometihing like this?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Comment: Have you tried it.?..but since `meta` is not an DOM **element** (AFAIK) I find it unlikely?

Comment: As the `<meta>` elements needs to be placed inisde `<head>` and all your other elements are inside of `<body>` there is no way to use this information with css. You would need to have a child selector (which not exists yet). You would need to use javascript or server side scripts to copy the content of this tag somewhere inside or on the `<body>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how your pages are built but could you not add a class to the body tag for the "brands" pages and then style as normal:

body with the class

.#whatever {display:none}

Comment: i cant add a class to the body tag because , im using virtuemart on joomla , and i want a certain category to have a different css